# Why is my program (sort_them function) not sorting?

Tags: function, pointers, structure

This is my first post.  I've search around but cannot find anything specific to my issue that has helped to resolve it.  When I try to dereference the pointer or apply pointer math in the function, things just aren't doing what they're supposed to.

For example:  *(ptr + a) should technically advance a pointer to whatever value I've set a to.  Instead, I just get an error that says "request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union".  That doesn't make sense because I've already declared and passed my structure pointer into the function.  If I use the :

"start_ptr->name.last + a" style, it compiles but doesn't sort anything.  I know this second version also isn't right when it comes to pointer math either.

So basically, what seems wrong is compiling, what seems correct is not and neither actually sort anything.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>

/* Structure definition */
/* -------------------- */

struct split
{
    char last[10];
    char first[10];
};

struct info
{
    struct  split name;
    char    address[20];
    char    city[15];
    char    state[3];
    long    zip;
    int     age;
    char    gender;
};  /* end struct info */


void sort_them(struct info *, char); // sort prototype

int main(void)  
{
/* Declare variables */
/* ----------------- */

struct info     people[] =
{

    {"Asimov", "Isaac", "15 Main St", "Worcestor", "MA", 01555, 23, 'M'},
    {"Smith", "Jane", "17 Make Peace", "Wallham", "ND", 10102, 28, 'F'},
    {"De Rippa", "Jack", "18 Able Way ", "Boston", "MA", 50503, 74, 'M'},
    {"Cobb", "Jim", "55 Elm St", "Ware", "MO", 61555, 65, 'M'},
    {"Kapone", "Al", "15 Morin Ave", "Idunno", "MN", 31333, 34, 'M'},
    {"Seigel", "Myron", "44 Wing Blvd West", "Sandwich", "WA", 02537,     21, 'M'},
    {"Thymes", "Mary", "88 Same Place", "Washington", "DC", 90555, 44, 'F'}

};

int             bad_sort;
int             num_people = sizeof(people) / sizeof(people[0]); //this will be the count of how many people there are!
char            sort_order;
char            big_name[22];





struct info *start_ptr = &people[0];
struct info *nums_ptr, *nums_end_ptr = &people[6];
char *big_ptr = &big_name[0];







printf ("\nWelcome to the People Structure Data Report Program\n");



do
{
        bad_sort = 1;

        printf ("\nEnter the sort order for the report: ");
        printf ("\n(N=Name, A=Age, S=State, Z=Zip code ' '=no sort)\n ");

/*               blank or return is allowed for no sorting of the data */

        sort_order = getchar();

        if(sort_order == '\n' || sort_order == ' ') break; 

        sort_order = toupper(sort_order);

        if ((sort_order == 'N') || (sort_order == 'A') || 
                    (sort_order == 'S') || (sort_order == 'Z'))
            bad_sort = 0;
        else
            printf("\nIncorrect Sort order selected, please re-enter:  ");

} while (bad_sort == 1);



switch (sort_order)
{
    case 'N':
        printf("Sort by Name  %i People.\n", num_people); 
        break;
    case 'A':
        printf("Sort by Age  %i People.\n", num_people); 
        break;
    case 'S':
        printf("Sort by State  %i People.\n", num_people); 
        break;
    case 'Z':
        printf("Sort by Zip  %i People.\n", num_people); 
        break;
    default:
        printf("No Sort selected  %i People.\n", num_people); 
        break;
}  /* end cases */

if(sort_order != ' ')
    sort_them (start_ptr, sort_order);


/* Print Report */
/* ------------ */

printf("\n\n                 The People Report\n\n");

printf ("\n\n%-20s%-20s %-15s %-5s %-6s %-3s %-6s", 
        "Name", "Address","City","State","Zip","Age","Gender");

printf ("%-20s%-20s %-15s %-5s %-6s %-3s %-6s\n", 
        "----", "------","----","-----","---","---","------");


for (nums_ptr = start_ptr; nums_ptr <= nums_end_ptr; nums_ptr++, start_ptr++)
{

    strcpy(big_ptr, start_ptr->name.last);
    strcat(big_ptr, ", ");
    strcat(big_ptr,start_ptr->name.first);



    printf ("%-20s%-20s %-15s  %-4s%.5ld    %-3i  %c\n", 
                                                                           big_ptr,start_ptr->address,start_ptr->city,start_ptr->state,start_ptr->zip,
            start_ptr->age,start_ptr->gender);      

} /* end for loop */



printf("\n\n");

return 0;

} /* end main */

void sort_them(struct info *start_ptr, char sort_by)
{
int a,b;
struct info temp;


for(a = 0; a < 6; a++)

    for(b = a + 1; b < 7; b++)
    {
        if(    (sort_by == 'N' && strcmp(start_ptr->name.last + a, start_ptr->name.last + b) > 0)
            || (sort_by == 'A' && start_ptr->age + a > start_ptr->age + b )
            || (sort_by == 'S' && strcmp(start_ptr->state + a, start_ptr->state + b) > 0)
            || (sort_by == 'Z' && (start_ptr->zip + a) > (start_ptr->zip + b) )  
          )


        {
            temp = *(start_ptr + a);
            *(start_ptr + a) = *(start_ptr + b);
            *(start_ptr + b) = temp;

        } /* end if  */


    } /* end inner for loop  */





};









/* end of sort them
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following line

```
 strcmp( start_ptr->name.last + a, start_ptr->name.last + b) > 0
```

should be changed like below

```
strcmp( (start_ptr + a)->name.last,  
        (start_ptr + b)->name.last  
      ) > 0
```

and so on with other comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no reason not to use array notation in C:

```
for(a = 0; a < 6; a++)
for(b = a + 1; b < 7; b++)
{
    if(    (sort_by == 'N' && strcmp(start_ptr[a].name.last, start_ptr[b].name.last) > 0)
        || (sort_by == 'A' && start_ptr[a].age > start_ptr[b].age )
        || (sort_by == 'S' && strcmp(start_ptr[a].state, start_ptr[b].state) > 0)
        || (sort_by == 'Z' && (start_ptr[a].zip) > (start_ptr[b].zip) )  
      )


    {
        temp = start_ptr[a];
        start_ptr[a] = start_ptr[b];
        start_ptr[b] = temp;

    } /* end if  */
```

The expression `start_ptr->name.last + a` adds a to `start_ptr[0].name.last` and is no "style" of pointer arithmetic.

Pointer arithmetic can be done bye `(ptr+a)` where `ptr` is advanced by `a*sizeof(*ptr)`, if *ptr points to a valid object. Otherwise *ptr produces a segfault (for example for ptr=NULL). Then you could use the type of *ptr: `sizeof(type)`, in our example: `sizeof(struct info)`.

Basically `*(ptr+a)` is the same as `ptr[a]` and `(ptr+a)` is `&ptr[a]`.

If you want to use the `->` operator, you need to write

```
(start_ptr+a)->name
```

for example.